# Deleting orphans from a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-delete

I am trying to clean up a table where there are quite a few orphaned items.

I am approaching this by checking to see if there is a relationship to another table by looking for null values.

```
   DELETE FROM table1 
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.ID = table2.ID
    WHERE table2.ID IS NULL
```

I get an error that the left outer join is not valid.

I am looking for suggestions on other ways that I can delete these orphans from this broken relationship

Answer (score 15, accepted):

try this:

```
DELETE  FROM        table1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM table2 WHERE table1.ID = table2.ID)
```

Comment: Response from mysql workbench : "You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column To disable safe mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Editor and reconnect."
I don't want to disable safe mode, that sounds so ... not safe.

Answer (score 29):

If you want to use the same syntax, here is how it could have been:

```
DELETE a 
FROM table1 a  
LEFT JOIN table2 b 
ON a.id = b.id 
WHERE b.id IS NULL
```

Comment: I don't understand why but this runs MUCH faster than @MaziarTaheriAbkenar solution. The query plans in SQL Server are slightly different between yours and his but your runs so much faster in my world. +1

Comment: @Smitty odd, I would have thought it was the same

Comment: This is the way to do it. A subquery is the wrong tool for this job.

Answer (score 1):

Table 1 should then be the Child Table containing the orphaned records. And Table 2 the parent table.

```
    DELETE ChildTable  
    FROM Table1 ChildTable    
    LEFT JOIN Table2 ParentTable 
    ON ChildTable.id = ParentTable.id 
    WHERE ParentTable.id IS NULL
```

A really helpful article.
[SQL JOINs make it easy to find and fix missing data](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/sql-joins-make-it-easy-to-find-and-fix-missing-data/)