# mysql where condition based on left join field

Tags: mysql, sql, logic

I am working on a logic where If the LEFT joint field is null then a condition in Where should not be applied. Can some one give me an idea how can It be done with only query.

I tried using IF CASE but its not helping,

Query:

```
SELECT *
FROM tableA ta
LEFT JOIN tableB tb ON tb.id = ta.id_c
WHERE ta.sales = 'Closed'
  AND tb.deleted=0
```

When **ta.id_c** is null, the condition in where **AND tb.deleted=0** shouldnt taken in to account.

Why? Because when there is a null value in the linking ID there is no selection of data for the query. Any help? thanks in advance.

Expected result:
Select columns of the tables.

Actual Table:

tableA:

```
id_c    sales  
   1    Closed 
   2    Closed
```

tableB:

```
   id  deleted 
   1    0
```

After Query: Current

```
id_c    sales   id  deleted 
   1    Closed  1   0
```

**EXPECTED**

```
id_c    sales   id    deleted 
   1    Closed  1       0
   2    Closed  NULL   NULL
```

Note: I cannot able to edit the LEFT JOIN conditions

Comment: What results are you not getting that you expect to get, or what results are you getting that you don't want to get?

Comment: updated.. the question @CGritton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given

```
create table tableA (
  id_c integer,
  sales varchar(255)
);

create table tableB (
  id integer,
  deleted bool
);

insert into tableA values (1, 'Closed'), (2, 'Closed');
insert into tableB values (1, 0);

SELECT *
FROM tableA ta
LEFT JOIN tableB tb ON tb.id = ta.id_c
WHERE
  (ta.sales = 'Closed' AND tb.deleted = 0) OR
  (ta.sales = 'Closed' AND tb.id is null)
```

or a little less wordy

```
WHERE
  (ta.sales = 'Closed') AND (tb.deleted = 0 OR tb.id is null);
```

**results in**

```
id_c    sales   id  deleted 
1   Closed  1   0
2   Closed  NULL    NULL
```

Comment: oh, i just saw that you can't edit the LEFT JOIN conditions.  i don't understand that; please explain more clearly why and what else you can't edit.

Comment: I dont want NULL, What i mean is in some record the ta.id_c is null, so the entire record is not displaying because the tb.deleted=0..

Comment: as you see how to give a data example in this solution, please clarify the data by giving the table structure and the example data, also including expected result.

Comment: I cant edit the JOINT, But i can change there where condition so if the ta.id_c is not null I can add the condtion 'AND tb.deleted=0'.

Comment: see my **UPDATE** pls

Comment: Solved the question ;)

Comment: Yup! Its working and wonderful solution.! Do you think this can be done in anyother way? different solutions ?

Comment: Maybe, I could not help but think [Foreign Keys](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757181/basics-of-foreign-keys-in-mysql) would prevent the [orphan sql rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6564034/deleting-orphans-from-a-table), but that requires a premeditated, design to the application and can't be done as a work around (not without some cleanup).